# what is layout editor quality setting in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

*what happen if i set the progress bar on Faster?
where i get the functionality details of android studio?

[image]

Comment: And what your test reveals?

Comment: @Marcin Oralowski  There is no effect if i set faster.

Comment: it should change the res preview for layouts